# Перенос базы пользователей (LocalDb) на SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-localdb

Мне необходимо перенести базу пользователей, которая по умолчанию у ASP.NET MVC храниться в локальной базе данных (`LocalDb`), на SQL Server. *Довольно таки неудобно оказалось хранить пользователей отдельно от базы, которая полностью связана с этими пользователями.*

Везде говорится о [способе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113209/how-to-transfer-asp-net-mvc-database-from-localdb-to-sql-server), где просто необходимо изменить `connectionString` и тогда система автоматически будет создавать **будущих** пользователей в указаном месте. Мне же необходимо каким-то образом перенести уже **имеющуюся базу**. *У меня накопилось около 500 учетных записей.*

Как все это правильно "провернуть". Ведь сайт еще в полной работе и эти файлы `aspnet-WebApplication1-20150706062157.mdf` просто так не скачать и не подключиться к ним?

Comment: ну как вариант: выбираем пользователей при помощи `select`, заворачиваем полученные значения в `insert`, который вставляет в новую бд, так поступаем со всеми необходимыми данными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда мне необходимо поработать с базой данных пользователей – БД которая хранится локально (`WebApplication1-20150706062157.mdf`), то поступаю следующим образом:

1. В `IIS` останавливаю *пул приложений* в котором находится мое веб-приложения. Делаю это для того, чтобы полностью освободит БД, иначе не то чтобы изменить, но и прочитать не могу.
2. C помощью `SSMS` или `VS` уже свободно подключаюсь к БД и произвожу
   необходимые мне манипуляции.
3. Отсоединяюсь от БД (из SSMS/VS).
4. Запускаю пул приложений, отключенный на шаге 1.

Быть может это не совсем стандартный способ, но такие вещи как создание ролей, подключение ролей к пользователям, удаление пользователя с помощью `SQL-запросов` для меня удобнее так.

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться мастером экспорта данных в MS Sql Management Studio

1. Открыть Management Studio и подключиться к localdb:

   - (localdb)\v11.0
   - (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB для VS2015
2. Выбрать нужную базу, нажать ПКМ->Задачи->Экспортировать данные. Откроется мастер.
3. В качестве источника данных выбрать `.NET Framework Data Provider for SqlServer` и в таблице свойств в поле `ConnectionString` ввести строку подключения к localdb: `Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` (см. п.1):
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Аналогично подключиться к целевому серверу. В моем случае, это локальный SQLEXPRES. Если необходимо, указать имя пользователя и пароль `Data Source=PC_NAME\SQLEXPRESS; user=sa; pasword=*****`. Нажать далее.
5. Выбрать пункт `Скопировать данные из одной или нескольких таблиц или представлений`. Далее.
6. Выбрать необходимые таблицы
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
7. Далее, далее => запустится мастер, который перенесет таблицы и сделает отчет.